# Replacing Chevy Cobalt battery

Tags: battery, chevrolet, cobalt

I have a 2008 Chevy Cobalt, battery in the trunk.
The battery was replaced with one without a hose.
Do I still need to attach a hose and where?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Its the wrong battery, get a proper battery with the hose connection.

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZihqDuw8VfY This should help

Comment: You had a vented battery. It MUST be replaced with a vented battery. There is no work around on this. Get a vented battery. The non-vented battery is not safe